# He didn't need asking twice - what's this grammar?

Tags: idiomatic-language, gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund

In one of the Paddington the Bear books, there's a scene where the characters plan to go shopping and explain Paddington what it is like to shop at a market. The following line is:

> Paddington didn't need asking twice and soon afterwards they all set
> off.

What puzzles me is this part in the very beginning of the sentence, *didn't need asking twice*. Have never seen such constructions before, I would say something 'He didn't need to be asked twice'. Is the construction above a some sort of fixed expression or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb need with the meaning of require can be followed by a gerund:

The car needs washing. (same as needs to be washed or is in need of washing)
The dog needs feeding. (same as needs to be fed or is in need of being fed)

Needs + gerund is just a standard non-formal way of saying it.

Paddington didn't need asking twice=
Paddington didn't need to be asked twice.

Merriam Webster says:
transitive verb

: to be in need of : REQUIRE

BrE uses this more than AmE but it is acceptable and understandable in AmE also. You often here it with will or another tense:
**That machine will need fixing.**
OR
**Her press releases have needed rewriting in the past**.

So, the grammar is: the verb need can take a gerund.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, you've been of great help!

Comment: "Need" is not transitive here. It has a non-finite clause as complement, not an object. Objects are NPs.

Comment: @BillJ I did not say that need was transitive. I said the verb need **takes** a gerund. Who cares what the grammar is called? What matters is using it properly and explaining it to a learner.

Comment: You quoted M-W as saying it was a transitive verb, which presumably you agree with, otherwise you wouldn't have mentioned it!

Comment: So every verb in that list following by a verb+ing is intransitive? He liked playing tennis? That is intransitive?

Answer (score 0):

> [*Paddington didn't need asking twice*] *and soon afterwards they all set*
> *off*.

Yes, it's kind of idiom ("enthusiastically accepted"). The bracketed gerund-participial (*ing*) clause has the same meaning as the infinitival clause "He didn't need to be asked twice". They are just two different idiomatic ways of saying the same thing.

This type of clause is called a catenative construction because there are two non-finite clauses back-to-back, i.e. the second clause, "asking twice", is complement to the first clause, "Paddington didn't need".

Comment: It is not an idiom per se. It is a verb that is followed by a gerund, like this list of verbs: https://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/gerund_list.htm

Comment: @Lambie Of course it's a kind of idiom. Grammatically, it's a catenative construction.

Comment: : an expression in the usage of a language that is peculiar to itself either in having a meaning that cannot be derived from the conjoined meanings of its elements (such as up in the air for "undecided") or in its grammatically atypical use of words (such as give way) Merriam Webster

Comment: @Lambie I'm perfectly aware of what an idiom is. I don't need a lesson in English grammar or meaning from you.

Answer (score -1):

It's correct, but it's so much more a British English thing, that to my Canadian ears, it's not even natural. I easily understand what it means, but because the other way is so much more natural, what I understand first is that **on two separate occasions** Paddington didn't need to be asked **at all**.

The grammar of *[ "need" + gerund ]* I'm fine with, but for some reason, with "twice" after it, it's unnatural and I will only use the *[ "need" + "to" + base form ]* version.